# Ruby Regex to Match Grayscale Color

Tags: ruby, regex

I want a ruby regex to match a hex greyscale color.

So it would match

```
#000000
#ababab
#ffffff
```

but NOT

```
#ccddcc
#afafa0
```

etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\h` is the ruby regex code for hexadecimal.  `(...)` captures a submatch, and `\1` lets you refer to the first submatch:

```
/#(\h\h)\1\1/
```

in irb:

```
>> %w{ #000000 #ababab #ffffff #ccddcc #afafa0 }.map { |s| s =~ /#(\h\h)\1\1/ }
=> [0, 0, 0, nil, nil]
```

Comment: Is `\h` new in 1.9? It works locally (with 1.9.2) but not on Rubular (with 1.8.7).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^#([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]?)\1\1$
```

which will match:

```
#000000
#aaa
#ababab
#ffffff
```

as you can see on Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/hDPrvr1dvu

It either repeats a single character 3 times (matching `#AAA`) or repeat a double char 3 times (matching `#666666` and `#121212`).

Comment: I would upvote, except your regex doesn't limit itself to hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: You can use `[[:xdigit:]]` in place of `[0-9a-fA-F]`, if desired.

Comment: @Wayne, thanks, didn't know Ruby accepted Posix character classes. Although I'm not a fan of them: I find them a bit long winded...

Comment: @Bart, I agree.  I just noticed yet another way to write it: Instead of `[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]?`, you can use `[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}`.  Or for even shorter-winded, `[0-9a-z]{1,2}` and add the /i flag to the regexp.